# Shape Name by Reference and Looping doesnt work

Tags: vba, excel, shapes

Im Creating a subroutine as below to Refer a Cell and coulor the shape.

In my Code the H value (Name) is not working. Please help.

```
Sub Erectioncolour()
    J = 9
    H = 1

    Do
        If Worksheets("Vertical Chart").Cells(J, 25).Value <> "" Then
            Worksheets("Visual Chart").Shapes(H).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(5, 0, 0)
        Else
            Worksheets("Visual Chart").Shapes(H).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End If

        J = J + 1 And H = H + 1
    Loop While J = 268
End Sub
```

Comment: `J = J + 1 And H = H + 1` remove `And` and put in separate lines

Comment: Tried. Its working for the first Shape. Doesnt work for the next shapes. I mean its not getting H = H+1

Comment: In your code, `H` is **not** referring to the shape's `.Name` property, but rather to its index position within the `Shapes` collection of the worksheet.  Are your shapes really named `1, 2, 3, etc`?

Comment: Also, your `Loop` statement is almost certainly wrong, this will evaluate the loop only once, since at the end of the loop, `J = 10` (i.e., `J <> 268`) so the loop will terminate.

Comment: Yes My shapes are named as 1,2,3 etc. Please suggest solution or correct my code.

Comment: Changed as J<268 But tell me how to refer the shape by name

Comment: Well it is difficult to suggest a solution since I can't actually verify the contents of your worksheet.  Unless you have manually renamed each shape (or done same through VBA), it is not likely they are actually named 1, 2, 3, etc.  What happens if you `Debug.Print Worksheets("Visual Chart").Shapes(2).Name`?

Comment: Any chance you can put your workbook on Google Docs or Dropbox so I can take a look at it?

Comment: Sure..Or tell me your email id. I will mail you the workbook.

Comment: Sent you via mail Please

Comment: If you step through this code manually using F8 in the VBE, you should easily identify the source of this problem...

Comment: Cant understand..Have u checked my mail.

Answer (score 0):

> In my Code the H value (Name) is not working.

Yes, it is actually working.

Your problem is with the conditional `If Worksheets("Vertical Chart").Cells(J, 25) <> ""`.  Row 25 in that worksheet is empty, after column K.  So for every value of `J` greater than 10, it will not apply the `RGB(5, 0, 0)`, but instead applies the `RGB(255, 255, 255)` as the False part of the test.

[image]

So the `True` part of your `If/Else` statement is only being executed once. After that, they all evaluate to `False`, so the shapes are being correctly (according to the code) applied with the following from your `Else` statement:

```
Worksheets("Visual Chart").Shapes(H).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
```

Solution:

You need to change your logic in the `If` statement, or, specify a non-white RGB value.

**Updated to explain how IF statements work...**

THere are two parts to your `If` statement, a `True` part which colors the shapes with `RGB(5, 0, 0)` and a `False` part which colors the shapes with `RGB(255, 255, 255)` (white).  As your file is currently configured, the statement evaluates `False` for every value of `J` in {9,11,12,..., 268}.  This is conditional based on the logic AND the data (or lack thereof) in the worksheet.

If you don't want these shapes to be white, then you need to assign a different RGB value. Which one you choose is up to you, for example `.RGB(6, 255, 255)` looks turquoise.

Or the other possibility is that your `If` statement's test is incorrect. If that is not correct, then I cannot help you until you describe how the test *should* be working, because the current test will always do what it is doing right now, until the cells in Row 25 are non-blank.

Comment: Sir, Non-white RGB value is required. Please suggest a logic in the if statement

Comment: It's **your** logic. I don't know what you're trying to do. Right now, it **only** applies the non-white RGB to the shape if the corresponding cell `Worksheets("Vertical Chart").Cells(J, 25) <> ""`.  If you don't know what you're trying to do, or if you don't understand a basic `If` statement, I can't help you.

Comment: The code reads the H value as Serial No as in the Selection Pane. But I want that to work or Read as the Shapes Name that why i renamed all the shapes as 1,2,3...etc

Comment: Its working till H = 30 since i have serially arranged the Shapes in Selection pane but cant do for all as it takes lot of time.

Comment: *i have serially arranged the Shapes in Selection pane but cant do for all as it takes lot of time*  I'm not really sure why you think this is my problem to solve. I'm not helping you any more.